# Connection between Embedding and LSTM and Dense layer

Tags: keras, lstm, embeddings

I am building a "predict next word" model using the following model architecture. The codes fine, but I have a few questions:

```
# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 50, input_length=seq_length))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())
```

Between the Embedding and LSTM layers, are there 50 connection weights, or 50 * 100 connection weights? Based on the documentation, this LSTM block contains 100 cells. So I am not sure how exactly does the Embedding layer connect to the LSTM layer?

Also, between LSTM(100) layer and the Dense(100, activation='relu') layer, are there 100 connection weights or 100 * 100 connection weights?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The embedding layer has an output shape of 50. The first LSTM layer has an output shape of 100. How many parameters are here? Take a look at [this blog](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) to understand different components of an LSTM layer.

Then you can get the number of parameters of an LSTM layer from the equations or from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38086903/10161091).

Now, between LSTM(100) layer and the Dense(100, activation='relu') layer, there should be 100*(100 + 1) parameters. The additional 1 is for the bias.